# Formatting (for money) with setText(String.valueOf)

Tags: java, formatting

In my code there are some calls to a method that set the values of some JTextFields

```
fields[7].setText(String.valueOf(inv.get(currentDisplay).feeValue()));
```

This works and it is doing what I want but the values look like this 81.65849999999999

How would I make the output of String.valueOf look like the normal output of

```
System.out.printf( "$%,.2f", getDollarAmount() )
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [this](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html) class. Here is an example that I think will help [here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Development-Class/Formatanumbertocurrency.htm). Here is the code from the example link:

```
import java.text.NumberFormat;

public class Mortgage {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    double payment = Math.random() * 1000;
    System.out.println("Your payment is ");
    NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();
    System.out.println(nf.format(payment));
  }
}
```

My only caution is that it does do rounding - there are methods you can play with to adjust this though...

Comment: NumberFormat did the job.  Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
locale = Locale.CANADA;
String str = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(locale).format(123.45);
//output: $123.45
```

Alternate:

```
NumberFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("'$'###.00");
String str = formatter.format(getDollarAmount());
```

Reference: [Formatting a Number Using a Custom Format](http://exampledepot.com/egs/java.text/FormatNum.html)